# WPF live Update from database

Tags: wpf, listbox, notifications, live, push-notification

I am building a multiuser WPF application (requirement is a desktop app), database SQL Server 2008.

There are two types of users.

The first type user will enter a record which would be stored in a table.

The second type user initially will be presented with a listbox with the records from the table. The requirement is that the listbox must be updated live (i.e. if a new record is entered by the first user the listbox must be updated).

Currently I have not yet implemented the Database functionality.
I am currently working with ObservableCollection and simulating this scenario.

I would like to know the best approach for achieving this.
Should i use a timer and keep querying the table? Is there a more efficient way?
Is this even possible (should I switch to ASP.NET?) ?

I would appreciate any suggestions and tips that you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), since it can raise an event (OnChange) in your code when the results of a query would change on the server (as the result of an INSERT or UPDATE from another user or process, for example)

An example of its use on CodeProject for a simple live chat application:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx

Comment: +1 We're using this in a very similar business case, and it provide what the OP needs. In short, you specify a `SELECT` query, and SQL Server fires a notification whenever the resultset of that query changes.